# Can't use paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN)); in android

Tags: android, porter-duff

I'm making a reflection effect in my image but I can't use this line

```
 paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
```

there is a red line is "DST_IN" saying it cannot be resolved or is not a field.
How does anyone can use it except me?
Is there any plugin or etc to use that line?
I tried to search it but I can't find any ways to use it.

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

just change it into this

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));